# Adding text to Matplot line graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i have a line graph that would be better represented if it showed the number along the graph similar to this http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/pascal-schetelat/8382651

the `slope` lines are beautiful. and that's im looking to do with my graphs but im not doing anything with `slopes` so im wondering if there's a way i can accomplish the same visual effect of adding the number along the line, for a simple line graph.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The slope graphs *are* line graphs. All you need to do is to install the slope package from github and then use it instead of the normal plotting command.

Comment: what im asking if to add the number along the line. i could do that. however i was wondering if there was a way to it without having to install a another library just to accomplish the same functionality

Comment: did you click the link? and did you read the comment above? i said i was looking to replicate the " number along the line" graph on the link provided. i took  Dov Grobgeld advice and installed the library.